# Passing List<Long> to Spring Data Repository as SDR Query Parameter

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the following interface which is extended by several of my repository interfaces:

```
public interface IdentifiableEntityRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    @RestResource(path="findAll")
    public List<T> findByIdIn(@Param("ids") List<ID> ids);

}
```

Here's an example of a repository that happens to have String IDs:

```
public interface FooRepository extends IdentifiableEntityRepository<Foo, String>, 
        PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, String> 
{
    ...
}
```

... and another example that happens to have Long IDs:

```
public interface BarRepository extends IdentifiableEntityRepository<Bar, Long>, 
        PagingAndSortingRepository<Bar, Long> 
{
    ...
}
```

For the String example, I'm able to successfully query the findAll endpoint like so:

```
GET /api/data/foo/search/findAll?ids=eenie,meenie,miney,moe
```

But for the Long example, a similar query produces a 500 server error

```
GET /api/data/bar/search/findAll?ids=1035,1036,1042,2048

{
  "timestamp": "2017-02-17T00:00:33.547Z",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
  "message": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [1035] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [1035] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]",
  "path": "/api/data/bar/search/findAll"
}
```

The IllegalArgumentException is thrown in Hibernate JPA, at `org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateCollectionValuedParameterBinding()`. When I put a breakpoint there, it's clear that the comma-separated string passed in as the "ids" query param is successfully parsed into a `List<String>` and then passed through the layers (spring-data-rest -> spring-data -> spring-data-jpa -> hibernate-jpa). The noted BaseQueryImpl method then iterates the String elements checking to see if they are instances of the expected Long type. They aren't, and thus, the IllegalArgugmentException.

I've also tried the following:

```
GET /api/data/bar/search/findAll?ids=1035l,1036l,1042l,2048l
```

...but this gave the same error.

**So here's the question**: I really want a common, generics-enhanced method declaration in the IdentifiableEntityRepository interface so that I can reuse it across many repositories. Is there a way to make the parsing of the "ids" query parameter type-aware so that it works with non-String IDs?